# Extracting tar from host to docker container

Tags: docker

I cannot understand from [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) how to extract a tar to a container with a single command: let's say:

```
tar xf ./tarfile.tar.gz | docker cp - $CONTAINERID:/var/www/html
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the tar archive itself as stdin

```
gzip -cd tarfile.tar.gz | docker cp - $CONTAINERID:/var/www/html

gunzip tarfile.tar.gz
docker cp - $CONTAINERID:/var/www/html < tarfile.tar
```

Remember that it's extremely routine to delete Docker containers, and when you do, their entire filesystem is lost.  It's usually better to use the `docker run -v` option to inject some part of the host filesystem into a container, and not try to use imperative commands like `docker cp` (or `docker exec`) that you'll have to repeat when you recreate the container.

```
mkdir html
(cd html && tar xf ../tarfile.tar.gz)
docker run -v "$PWD/html:/var/www/html" ...
```